Adding dates to a DAX sumx/switch/filter query
I have inherited an existing DAX statement in a power BI report which calculates fees based on sources and products;
Fee= SUMX(
    FILTER(
        'Accounts',
        AND(
            RELATED('Processes'[processtype_group]) = "NEWBUS",
            RELATED('Transaction classes'[transaction_class_code]) = "Undwrite")
    ),
    SWITCH(
        RELATED(Source[source name]) & " " & RELATED(Products[Product name]),
        "Source1 Product1", -25,
        "Source1 Product2", -25,
        "Source1 Product3", -50,
        "Source1 Product4", -25,
        "Source2 Product1", -41.60,
        "Source2 Product2", -41.60,
        "Source2 Product3", -53.60,
        "Source2 Product4", -35.60)
        )

I want to add date ranges where suppliers have changed their fees.
Its further complicated by the data coming from multiple tables, but how can I add the date ranges so the right fee shows depending on when the product was sold?
I have tried this
Fee2 = sumx(
    FILTER(
        'Accounts',
        AND(
            RELATED('Processes'[processtype_group]) = "NEWBUS",
            RELATED('Transaction classes'[transaction_class_code]) = "Undwrite")
    ),
    SWITCH(
        true(),
        RELATED(Source[source name]) & " " & RELATED(Products[Product name]),
        "Source1 Product1", -25,
        "Source1 Product2", -25,
        "Source1 Product3", -50,
        "Source1 Product4", -25,
        "Source2 Product1" && Accounts[posted_date] < DATE(2024,03,01), -41.60,
        "Source2 Product2" && Accounts[posted_date] < DATE(2024,03,01), -41.60,
        "Source2 Product3" && Accounts[posted_date] < DATE(2024,03,01), -53.60,
        "Source2 Product4" && Accounts[posted_date] < DATE(2024,03,01), -35.60,
        "Source2 Product1" && Accounts[posted_date] >= DATE(2024,03,01), -43.00,
        "Source2 Product2" && Accounts[posted_date] >= DATE(2024,03,01), -43.00,
        "Source2 Product3" && Accounts[posted_date] >= DATE(2024,03,01), -55.00,
        "Source2 Product4" && Accounts[posted_date] >= DATE(2024,03,01), -36.85)
        )

But I get an error saying "Function 'SWITCH' does not support comparing values of type Text with values of type True/False"

Is this a working solution for you? I have recreated your question with some sample data.
Fee = 
VAR _Table = FILTER(
        'Accounts Table',
        RELATED('Processes Table'[processtype_group]) = "NEWBUS" &&
        RELATED('Transaction Classes'[transaction_class_code]) = "Undwrite"
)
RETURN SUMX(
    _Table,
    VAR Concat = RELATED('Source table'[source_name]) & " " & RELATED(Products[product_name])
    VAR DateApplicable = 'Accounts Table'[posted_date]
    RETURN 
        SWITCH(
            TRUE(),
            (Concat = "Source1 Product1"), -25,
            (Concat = "Source1 Product2"), -25,
            (Concat = "Source1 Product3"), -50,
            (Concat = "Source1 Product4"), -25,
            (Concat = "Source2 Product1") && (DateApplicable < DATE(2024,03,01)), -41.60,
            (Concat = "Source2 Product2") && (DateApplicable < DATE(2024,03,01)), -41.60,
            (Concat = "Source2 Product3") && (DateApplicable < DATE(2024,03,01)), -53.60,
            (Concat = "Source2 Product4") && (DateApplicable < DATE(2024,03,01)), -35.60,
            (Concat = "Source2 Product1") && (DateApplicable >= DATE(2024,03,01)), -43.00,
            (Concat = "Source2 Product2") && (DateApplicable >= DATE(2024,03,01)), -43.00,
            (Concat = "Source2 Product3") && (DateApplicable >= DATE(2024,03,01)), -55.00,
            (Concat = "Source2 Product4") && (DateApplicable >= DATE(2024,03,01)), -36.85
        )
)


The switch in this measure checks whether one or both conditions are true, using variables upfront to make sure you do not have to repeat the code elsewhere.

Final result:
table with result
Your initial solution didn't work because you inserted the 'RELATED(Source[source name]) & " " & RELATED(Products[Product name])' as a second argument inside switch, which is then your first 'case'. It would basically check whether TRUE() = Source1 Product1", which makes no sense and Power BI correctly addresses this.
I do have to mention that this solution is not robust and very verbose. Perhaps you could work with another lookup table where you define the different conditions, and you can just lookup for each specific combination (in this case the concatenation and the date) which fee should be applied? This is more maintable and less code need to be written.
